# rails 4 application view helper possible refactor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

In three different layouts I have to display social links utilizing three different configurations.  I wanted to setup a few methods to handle this, but I 
feel like this code could be optimized further.  The section attached can be called by `social_links(["show_div","show_email"])` for example which will
trigger various configurations from the methods.  Is this overkill?  The other thought I had was to break these down even further and only include the 
link instead of the html code.

Tips to refactor? Optimize?

In my `application_helper.rb` file:

```
  # shared social links displayed in multiple layouts
  def social_links(view_options = nil)
    html=%(<ul class="social-links">)
    html+=%(<li>) + blog_link(view_options) + %(</li>)
    html+=%(<li>) + podcast_link(view_options) + %(</li>)
    html+=%(<li>) + twitter_link(view_options) + %(</li>)
    html+=%(<li>) + instagram_link(view_options) + %(</li>)
    html+=%(<li>) + facebook_link(view_options) + %(</li>)
    html+=%(<li>) + pinterest_link(view_options) + %(</li>)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_email")
      html+=%(<li>) + contact_us_link(view_options) + %(</li>)
    end
    html+=%(</ul>)
    raw(html.strip)
  end

  def twitter_link(view_options = nil)
    html=%(<a href="#{ENV['SOCIAL_TWITTER']}" target="_blank">)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(<div>)
    end
    html+=%(<i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i>)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_desc")
      html+=%(Twitter)
    end
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(</div>)
    end
    html+=%(</a>)
    raw(html.strip)
  end

  def instagram_link(view_options = nil)
    html=%(
      <a href="#{ENV['SOCIAL_INSTAGRAM']}" target="_blank">)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(<div>)
    end
    html+=%(<i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_desc")
      html+=%(Instagram)
    end
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(</div>)
    end
    html+=%(</a>)
    raw(html.strip)
  end

  def facebook_link(view_options = nil)
    html=%(
      <a href="#{ENV['SOCIAL_FACEBOOK']}" target="_blank">)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(<div>)
    end
    html+=%(<i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i>)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_desc")
      html+=%(Facebook)
    end
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(</div>)
    end
    html+=%(</a>)
    raw(html.strip)
  end

  def pinterest_link(view_options = nil)
    html=%(
      <a href="#{ENV['SOCIAL_PINTEREST']}" target="_blank">)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(<div>)
    end
    html+=%(<i class="fa fa-pinterest-square"></i>)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_desc")
      html+=%(Pinterest)
    end
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(</div>)
    end
    html+=%(</a>)
    raw(html.strip)
  end

  def blog_link(view_options = nil)
    html=%(
      <a href="#{ENV['SOCIAL_BLOG']}" target="_blank">)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(<div>)
    end
    html+=%(<i class="fa fa-rss-square"></i>)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_desc")
      html+=%(Blog)
    end
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(</div>)
    end
    html+=%(</a>)
    raw(html.strip)
  end

  def podcast_link(view_options = nil)
    html=%(
      <a href="#{ENV['SOCIAL_PODCAST']}" target="_blank">)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(<div>)
    end
    html+=%(<i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-right"></i>)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_desc")
      html+=%(Podcast)
    end
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(</div>)
    end
    html+=%(</a>)
    raw(html.strip)
  end

  def contact_us_link(view_options = nil)
    html=%(
      <a href="/contact_us" target="_blank">)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(<div>)
    end
    html+=%(<i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>)
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_desc")
      html+=%(Contact)
    end
    if view_options && view_options.include?("show_div")
      html+=%(</div>)
    end
    html+=%(</a>)
    raw(html.strip)
  end
```

**UPDATE ONE: Partial Method**

After further conversation and thought, I changed the helpers to a partial `_social_links.html.slim`

```
- social_twitter = "<i class='fa fa-twitter-square'></i>".html_safe
- social_instagram = "<i class='fa fa-instagram'></i>".html_safe
- social_facebook = "<i class='fa fa-facebook-square'></i>".html_safe
- social_pinterest = "<i class='fa fa-pinterest-square'></i>".html_safe
- social_rss = "<i class='fa fa-rss-square'></i>".html_safe
- social_podcast = "<i class='fa fa-caret-square-o-right'></i>".html_safe
- social_email = "<i class='fa fa-envelope'></i>".html_safe
ul[class="social-links"]
  li
    a[href="#{ENV['SOCIAL_TWITTER']}" target="_blank"]
      - if collection && collection.include?("show_div")
        div
          = social_twitter
      - else
        = social_twitter
      - if collection && collection.include?("show_desc")
        | Twitter
  li
    a[href="#{ENV['SOCIAL_INSTAGRAM']}" target="_blank"]
      - if collection && collection.include?("show_div")
        div
          = social_instagram
      - else
        = social_instagram
      - if collection && collection.include?("show_desc")
        | Instagram
  li
    a[href="#{ENV['SOCIAL_FACEBOOK']}" target="_blank"]
      - if collection && collection.include?("show_div")
        div
          = social_facebook
      - else
        = social_facebook
      - if collection && collection.include?("show_desc")
        | Facebook
  li
    a[href="#{ENV['SOCIAL_PINTEREST']}" target="_blank"]
      - if collection && collection.include?("show_div")
        div
          = social_pinterest
      - else
        = social_pinterest
      - if collection && collection.include?("show_desc")
        | Pinterest
  li
    a[href="#{ENV['SOCIAL_BLOG']}" target="_blank"]
      - if collection && collection.include?("show_div")
        div
          = social_rss
      - else
        = social_rss
      - if collection && collection.include?("show_desc")
        | Blog
  li
    a[href="#{ENV['SOCIAL_PODCAST']}" target="_blank"]
      - if collection && collection.include?("show_div")
        div
          = social_podcast
      - else
        = social_podcast
      - if collection && collection.include?("show_desc")
        | Podcast
  - if collection && collection.include?("show_email")
    li
      a[href="/contact_us" target="_blank"]
        - if collection && collection.include?("show_div")
          div
            = social_email
        - else
          = social_email
        - if collection && collection.include?("show_desc")
          | Contact
```

The partial can be invoked by:
`render partial: "layouts/social_links", locals: { collection: ["show_div","show_email"]}` or 
`render partial: "layouts/social_links", locals: { collection: nil}`

**UPDATE TWO: OO Method suggest below**

This can be called like:

```
social_links()
social_links(show_desc: true, show_list: %w{contact})
social_links(show_div: true, show_list: %w{contact})
```

In the folder /helpers/social_link I have my general helper:

```
module SocialLink
  module SocialLinkHelper
  # ****************************************************************************************************
  # ****************************************************************************************************
  DEFAULT_SOCIAL_PROVIDERS = %w{twitter facebook instagram pinterest blog podcast}

  def social_links(options={})
    content_tag :ul, class: "social-links" do
      provider_link(options)
    end
  end

  def provider_link(options={})
    social_providers = DEFAULT_SOCIAL_PROVIDERS
    social_providers = social_providers + options[:show_list] if options[:show_list]
    social_providers.each do |provider|
      klass = "SocialLink::SocialLinkClass::#{provider.titleize}Link".constantize
      link  = klass.new(options)
      concat link.generate
    end
  end

  # ****************************************************************************************************
  # ****************************************************************************************************
  end
end
```

In the folder /helpers/social_link I have my control class:

```
module SocialLink
  module SocialLinkClass

    class SocialBase < ActionView::Base
      include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper

      def initialize(options)
        @show_div = options[:show_div] || nil
        @show_desc = options[:show_desc] || nil
      end

      def generate
        content_tag :li do
          content = content_tag(:i, nil, class: self.class.icon)
          content = content + self.class.description.titleize if @show_desc
          content = "<div>#{content}</div>" if @show_div
          link_to(content.html_safe, self.class.link)
        end
      end
    end

    # ****************************************************************************************************
    class ContactLink < SocialBase
      def self.link
        "/contact_us"
      end
      def self.description
        "contact"
      end
      def self.icon
        "fa fa-envelope"
      end
    end
    # ****************************************************************************************************
    class BlogLink < SocialBase
      def self.link
        ENV['SOCIAL_BLOG']
      end
      def self.description
        "blog"
      end
      def self.icon
        "fa fa-rss-square"
      end
    end
    # ****************************************************************************************************
    class PodcastLink < SocialBase
      def self.link
        ENV['SOCIAL_PODCAST']
      end
      def self.description
        "podcast"
      end
      def self.icon
        "fa fa-caret-square-o-right"
      end
    end
    # ****************************************************************************************************
    class PinterestLink < SocialBase
      def self.link
        ENV['SOCIAL_PINTEREST']
      end
      def self.description
        "pinterest"
      end
      def self.icon
        "fa fa-pinterest-square"
      end
    end
    # ****************************************************************************************************
    class InstagramLink < SocialBase
      def self.link
        ENV['SOCIAL_INSTAGRAM']
      end
      def self.description
        "instagram"
      end
      def self.icon
        "fa fa-instagram"
      end
    end
    # ****************************************************************************************************
    class TwitterLink < SocialBase
      def self.link
        ENV['SOCIAL_TWITTER']
      end
      def self.description
        "twitter"
      end
      def self.icon
        "fa fa-twitter-square"
      end
    end
    # ****************************************************************************************************
    class FacebookLink < SocialBase
      def self.link
        ENV['SOCIAL_FACEBOOK']
      end
      def self.description
        "facebook"
      end
      def self.icon
        "fa fa-facebook-square"
      end
    end
    # ****************************************************************************************************

  end
end
```

**UPDATE THREE: My buddy @drewtempelmeyer  approach**

File: _social_link.html.erb

```
<%= social_icon service, collection %>
<% if show_desc?(collection) %>
  | <%= service.titleize %>
<% end %>
```

File: profile.html.erb

```
<%= render_social_link 'facebook', %w(show_div show_desc) %>
```

File: social_helper.rb

```
module SocialHelper
  def render_social_link(service = 'facebook', collection = nil)
    render partial: 'shared/social_link', locals: {
      service: service, collection: collection
    }
  end

  def show_div?(collection)
    collection && collection.include?('show_div')
  end

  def show_desc?(collection)
    collection && collection.include?('show_desc')
  end

  def social_icon(service, collection)
    content = content_tag(:li, nil, class: "fa fa-#{service.downcase}")
    content = "<div>#{content}</div>" if show_div?(collection)
    content
  end
end
```

Comment: I would use partials instead of view helpers.

Comment: @sevenseacat You know I originally had it setup with partials, but I thought the conditionals would be easier in a helper.  Hmmm.... You have a point there. Is there a performance boost one way or the other?

Comment: view helpers are likely better for performance, but horrible for readability especially when as messy as detailed here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: To me, helpers are used to do calculations and return a variable like int or string or array. A partial is to render the view html, haml, erb, etc. So you might need a combination of both to refactor this code, not just one.

Comment: @sonnyhe2002 that is an interesting concept.  How would you break this up?

Comment: @sevenseacat true, I want to make it easier to read... hmmm... I wonder if should just use a partial with passed variables.

Comment: If you can write this in a partial with all the logics in it, then I can refactor it for you.

Comment: @sonnyhe2002 I am taking a stab at breaking this up now, stay tuned :)

Comment: great, I be waiting. :)

Comment: @sonnyhe2002 I just updated my comments, but I am also reviewing Billy's below.

Comment: @sonnyhe2002 what do you think of what is currently setup? thoughts on how to correct this?

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond. Your second updated looks much cleaner since each method is not generating a lot of html, And it also split it into different classes. For Update 2, is it in the helpers folder?

Comment: @sonnyhe2002 ok,after 3 different approaches what do you think of the final outcome?

Comment: Most of the logic is in the helpers and the code is concise and clear.  I think it is nicely refactored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a good use case of applying OOP on view logic. Partials can also do the job but with too much options it will looks messy.

Starting with a general helper `social_links` is nothing wrong. Helper is just to help the view.

But later, you need classes to do the detailed job.

Your view which calls the helper

```
<%= social_links show_div: 'foo' %>
```

The general helper

```
SOCIAL_PROVIDERS = ['Twitter', 'Facebook', 'GooglePlus']

def social_links(options)
  content_tag :ul do
    provider_link(options)
  end
end

def provider_links(options)
  SOCIAL_PROVIDERS.each do |provider|
    klass = "#{provider}Link".constantize
    link  = klass.new(options)
    concat link.generate
  end    
end
```

Then the classes

```
class SocialLink
  def self.link
    "#"
  end

  def initialize(options)
    @show_div = options.try(:show_div)
    @show_desc = options.try(:show_div)
  end

  def generate
    content_tag :li do
      concat main_link
      concat show_div_link if @show_div
      concat show_desc_link if @show_desc
    end
  end

  private
  def main_link
    # Your html
    # call self.class.link here
  end

  def show_div_link
    # You html
  end

  def show_desc_link
    # You html
  end
end

class TwitterLink < SocialLink
  def self.link
    ENV['SOCIAL_TWITTER']
  end
end
```

These are demo code but you got the idea

Comment: interesting approach, I like this a little more than partials

Comment: in a rails 4 project, where do you think this would be placed ideally.

Comment: Anywhere within /app would be okay. You can put the classes in direcotries like /app/helpers/social_links

Comment: bummer, when I try to add them to "/app/helpers/social_links" I get a " Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant " error :(

Comment: ok, I got past that, however, I am getting a "uninitialized constant TwitterLink" error now. thoughts?

Comment: The cause is classes are not loaded by Rails. Try to put them into another directory say app/services/social_links etc. All files under '/app' should be loaded by Rails automatically.

Comment: After a bit of trouble, I was able to get them to load. I updated what I am currently using. Here are a few issues I am seeing. If you compare to what the partials had, I need a way to provide 3 variations of the link. One with the desc included, one wrapped in a div, and the other is just the plain link.  Thoughts?

Comment: I ended up going with you approach, let me know what you think.  Cheers.

Comment: Chris, nice you have got it done. I think such pattern can be applied when logic in partial could be complicated, otherwise partial would be simpler to use.